# How to do a 'count' for several criteria at once

Tags: sqlite, count

I am very new to SQL and am using SQLite 3 to run basket analysis on sales data.

The relevant columns are the product ID, a unique transaction ID (which identifies the basket) and the product quantity. Where a customer has bought more than one product type, the unqiue transaction ID is repeated.

I am wanting to count the number of baskets where the customer has bought 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and more than 5 items in order to analyse what percentage of customers only bought 1 item.

The code I am using is:

```
select count (*) as One from (select uniqID, sum(qty) as total from otcdata3 group by uniqID having total > 0) where total = 1;
select count (*) as Two from (select uniqID, sum(qty) as total from otcdata3 group by uniqID having total > 1) where total = 2;
select count (*) as Three from (select uniqID, sum(qty) as total from otcdata3 group by uniqID having total > 1) where total = 3; 
select count (*) as Four from (select uniqID, sum(qty) as total from otcdata3 group by uniqID having total > 1) where total = 4; 
select count (*) as Five from (select uniqID, sum(qty) as total from otcdata3 group by uniqID having total > 1) where total = 5; 
select count (*) as Six from (select uniqID, sum(qty) as total from otcdata3 group by uniqID having total > 1) where total = 6; 
select count (*) as Sevenplus from (select uniqID, sum(qty) as total from otcdata3 group by uniqID having total > 1) where total > 6;
```

This code does work but firstly, as you can see, it is rather unwieldy looking and secondly, the data comes out in the following format when I open it in Excel:

```
One
1353697
Two
483618
Three
166148
Four
76236
Five
35079
Six
18904
Sevenplus
27896
```

Ideally I would like the number of items along the top, with the number of baskets meeting that criteria underneath.  Whilst I can obviously sort the problem out manually at the moment, I need to run similar analysis on a much bigger scale soon!

Any suggestions on how to write the code so that it structures it the way I want would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To clarify: the data comes out in excel in one column, not one row, but my formatting changed when I posted my question!

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted answer, if it solves your problem. I spend 15 minutes to find a solution for your problem! Why? Because I wanted to help you, and collect scores for myself! Did I waste my time?

Comment: No not at all, sorry!  I didn't realise I could accept answers - new to forums too.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for rude tone of voice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
select
  case
    when total=1 then 'One'
    when total=2 then 'Two'
    when total=3 then 'Three'
    when total=4 then 'Four'
    when total=5 then 'Five'
    when total=6 then 'Six'
    when total=7 then 'SevenPlus'
  end,
  count(total)
from
  (select case when count(uniqID) <= 6 then count(uniqID) else 7 end as total from otcdata3 group by uniqID) as totals
group by total
order by total
```

This returns two columns, the first column is a text representing the number of items in the transaction, and the second column is the number of distinct purchases with that number of items.